# onMessageReceived not triggered when app is in foreground

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

In my app I want to receive FCM messages even when the app is in foreground. So I've set everything up according to https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#sample-receive

Yet while my app is in the foreground, the `onMessageReceived` method is not called. Note that when my app is in background it gets the notifications, so the connection to FCM itself works fine.

`application` part of my **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
    android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_ic_notification" />

<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
    android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />

<service
    android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

**MyFirebaseMessagingService.kt**

```
class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {
    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
        Timber.i("onMessageReceived") // never called
    }
}
```

I send my notifications using the FCM console. Any idea what I am doing wrong? Why is `onMessageReceived` not called while my app is in the foreground?

Comment: When I require such behavior, I implement data messages instead of notification messages. If doing like so, every notification in every app state would be passed to onMessageReceived method.

Comment: that's a workaround, but not a solution ):

Comment: I think offered workaround much better because you will have one entry point for processing notification payload.

Comment: your single entry point is a positive thing. yet I am wondering why my example isn't working, as I am following the official documentation.

Comment: I implement simple example with FCM and in my case it works: in the foreground onMessageReceived called as expected when I send notification message from Notification Composer. Maybe it's somehow caused by using Kotlin? I used Java.

Comment: thanks, I guess I will also switch to the data solution. however, I am curious, so I added a bounty :-)

Comment: I think your code work fine if you said when app in background it show notification instead, did you try you Log.i instead of Timber.i :D

Answer (score 0):

try replacing your service tag in the manifest file with :

```
<service
    android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>

<service
    android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

in the onMessageReceived() refer here you can get the notification / data payload :

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String TAG = "FCM Service";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
        }

        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " +
                    remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }

    }

}
```

You can refer [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive) for more information.

Comment: Where did you get the "MyFirebaseInstanceIDService" from? I've never seen this, it's also not mentioned on the documentation you linked. Still have to test it.